# Creating a jar with JUnit tests for classes implemented outside the jar file

Tags: java, unit-testing, jar

I want to setup something like the following:

- Create a set of JUnit tests for a certain class X and its methods.
- Distribute these tests, but without giving away the source code.
- People implementing class X will be able to add these tests to their project and run them against their implementation to see if the tests are passing.

My idea is to use a .jar file that contains the Test classes.
Then, the implementer of class can add the test .jar file to their project and run the tests.

My problem is that when I start to define the test method,
I need to create an object of class X,
but class X is not defined yet - it will only be defined by the implementaters.

Is there a way to setup this kind of scheme?

Comment: Create the class X yourself, then write the test class and compile it against your X class, and create the jar containing only the test class. Implementors will run the test you provide against their own X class (which of course must have the same name, package constructors and methods as yours).

Comment: Create an empty implementation you can compile your tests against, but fail the tests and are not included in the jar?

Comment: @JBNizet (and daniu) - Didnt know that certain files could be omitted from the jar. I will try this solution. Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose f this "testing jar"? Unittest are part of the *documentation* and you cannot expect a proper implementation if the implementer does not know the code of your unittests.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle - its to support a kind of programming competition. Some test cases are given with the problem description, but others are "hidden" to promote that the solutions are generic and not hardcoded to the specific test cases.

Comment: @daniu - How do I exclude the files from the .jar? Netbeans indicates that the .class files cannot be excluded. I tried doing it by opening the .jar in winrar and manually deleting the files, but I'm not sure this is a good approach... Thanks.

Comment: @MyNameIsZero I don't use NetBeans, so I can't tell you how to do that there exactly. In Eclipse, you'd create two separate projects with one dependent of the other, which would result in two jars; I'd be surprised if you can't do that in NetBeans.